# Task : Iterate through the array using a for loop and add 10 credits to all users

Tags: javascript, json

The output gives me hint that the person on position 0 didn't get 10 credits, but in output, I see added 10 credits more (60);

I am a bit confused. This question may seem stupid, but I just need a reevaluation.

```js
var users = [
    {name: 'asdfasdf', credits: 50},
    {name: 'asasdfdf', credits: 10},
    {name: 'asdasdffasdf', credits: 11},
    {name: 'weewrwe', credits: 1},
    {name: 'werwer', credits: 190},
    {name: 'sdfsdf', credits: 100},
    {name: 'dfgdfg', credits: 0},
];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var obj = users[i];
}
console.log((obj.credits)+ 10);
```

Comment: even with the edits, this snipped doesn't work as described...

Comment: `var obj = users[i];` will just assign to obj for each user and you will end up with the last user you add 10 to

Comment: You may mean `for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  users[i].credits+=10;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var obj = users[i];` will just assign to obj for each user and you will end up with the last user you add 10 to

Your script would work if you do

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { users[i].credits+=10; }
```

But this is enough and more modern

```
users.forEach(user => user.credits += 10)
```

Example:

```js
const users = [{name: 'asdfasdf', credits: 50},{name: 'asasdfdf', credits: 10},{name: 'asdasdffasdf', credits: 11},{name: 'weewrwe', credits: 1},{name: 'werwer', credits: 190},{name: 'sdfsdf', credits: 100},{name: 'dfgdfg', credits: 0}];

const amt = 10;
users.forEach(user => user.credits += amt)

console.log("Credits: ",users.map(user => user.credits).join(",")); // show just the credits

console.log(users); // show the users
```

Comment: @AnaBošnjaković You coudl do `console.log(users.map(user => user.credits))`

Comment: Prettier: `console.log("Credits: ",users.map(user => user.credits).join(","))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [
    {name: 'asdfasdf', credits: 50},
    {name: 'asasdfdf', credits: 10},
    {name: 'asdasdffasdf', credits: 11},
    {name: 'weewrwe', credits: 1},
    {name: 'werwer', credits: 190},
    {name: 'sdfsdf', credits: 100},
    {name: 'dfgdfg', credits: 0},
];

users.forEach(element => {
    if(element.credits != null) {
        element.credits = parseInt(element.credits) + 10;
    }
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: it's failing on adding to the last one

Comment: @HakanDilek Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the code snippet, accordingly.

Comment: great. looks ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var len = users.length;
for(var i = 0; i <= len; i++){
    
    users[i].credits+=10;
}
console.log(users);
```